# Fixing Bootstrap Table Column Width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I want to fix the width of particular columns in my Bootstrap table.  I have tried everything I could find on the documentation and forum:

Adding the `data-width` attribute to the `<th>` tag pursuant to the [Bootstrap Table documentation](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/):

```
<th data-width= 20 data-field="0" data-sortable="true" data-align="left" data-valign="middle">Car Model</th>
```

Adding `class="col-xs-4"` to the `<th>` tag:

```
<th class="col-xs-4" data-field="0" data-sortable="true" data-align="left" data-valign="middle">Car Model</th>
```

and lastly, changing the CSS property of the column:

```
.table tr td:nth-child(3) {width:50%;}
```

Unfortunately, none of the methods above worked.  I wonder if I have written the wrong code or some of my codes are conflicting with each other.  I would very much appreciate your help!

Here is my table:

http://jsfiddle.net/mademoiselletse/bypbqboe/56/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table-cells take your sizes as suggested, and try to use them if they can, but if the content doesn't allow it, then your sizes won't be respected.....unless you use the following property on your table:

`table-layout: fixed`

I may have oversimplified a little, read more about the exact reason why this works (assuming your first row contains small amounts of text - which it usually does because they are usually column headers), here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout

Comment: That solves the problem indeed!  Thank you very much!  Is there a way to wrap the content in the header given the width (just like how the body of the table adjusts its cell height based on its content, given the width of the column)?  I tried accomplishing it by setting the height of the header but nothing changed.  Ideally I would want the header to be displayed in 2 lines. Thank you very much!

Comment: You can't wrap `td`'s (or `th`'s) inside a `tr` - everything inside a `tr` will always be displayed on one row. For that, you'd need to ditch the `table` markup altogether and make a pseudo-table using `div`'s that you can manipulate better at different breakpoints.